# Xamarin iOS Notification Content Extension Unknown Application Error

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to get a Notification Content Extension working in my Xamarin iOS app.  I had a Notification Service Extension working fine that added an image.  However I can not get the content extension to work.

Everything is built fine.  All settings match between the app and the extension.  All settings are in info.plist. The target platforms match. The app has a reference to the extension and I have not modified the extension from the default mac template.

I checked the iOS log and this is the relevant error:

```
SpringBoard [com.mydomain.myapp] No extension available for bundle

SpringBoard [com.mydomain.myapp] Error was encountered trying to find service extension: error=Error Domain=UNErrorDomain Code 1904 "Unknown application"
```

I've tried deleting and readding the extension.  I've tried deleting the app and reinstalling.

Almost all the settings except the info.plist settings are the same as the service extension that worked.  I even tried keeping the service extension but changing the settings to the content extension (com.apple.usernotifications.content-extension etc.) but as soon as i do i get the unknown application error.

Has anyone run into this or have any idea what this error means?

**Update:**

I have created a simple Xamarin Forms test app on a Mac with xcode 10.1.  and VS Community 7.8.2.  Selected Release Mode. Only code I added was to register for my push notifications.  I set the deployment target to 12.1.  I unchecked all compiler optimzations except to strip debugger symbols.

I added a Notification Content Extension.  Changed no code.  Selected Release Mode. Set target to 12.1 (tried others as well).   I unchecked all compiler optimzations except to strip debugger symbols. Set Entitlement for push notifications.  Set my UNNotificationExtensionCategory.

Sent notification and get same error on iOS.  I can't be the first one to try this.

**Update:**

To clarify the app does not crash, the customized notification just does not show up.  This is because of the SpringBoard error that says unknown application when trying to find the extension.  My payload is:

```
{
    "aps":
    {
        "alert":"Notification Hub test notification",
        "mutable-content":"1",
        "category" : "critical",
        "sound": "alert.wav"
    },
}
```

Comment: Have you gone over the official guide for this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/advanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos#creating-custom-user-interfaces

Comment: did exactly like the guide and checked all settings.  not sure what the "unknown application" error means.  is it talking about the app or extension?  there seems to be no info on this error.

Comment: What's your real problem? The content extension doesn't appear in the notification? Or you sent a noticafication and your app crashed with the error? And what's your payload looks like? Can you provide a simple demo to reproduce the problem as I can't reproduce the problem on my side.

Comment: Jack... i updated the question to clarify.  Are you saying you created a Xamarin project, added a notification content extension and it worked?  are you using Xamarin or xcode?  I have the simplest xamarin project that reproduces which i could send to you.

Comment: Ok, you can upload your project to Github for test and give us a link to download . I'm using Xamarin.

Comment: I've uploaded a simple app created from VS 7.8.2 and xcode 10.1.  https://github.com/JSojourn/NCExtension.  I removed the endpoint in appdelegate.cs.  Let me know if you have any problems.  any help is appreciated.

Comment: anyone reproduce this with xcode 10.1. and VS Community 7.8.2?

Answer (score 2):

Please verify,

I was having the same issue, my device was ios 12 OS and the deployment target was the latest.

**Make sure your application deployment target and extension deployment target is the same.**

That solved my issue.

Comment: This fixed it for me, thank you!

For anyone not sure where to find this. In "Build Settings", "Targeted Device Family" and "iOS Deployment Target" didn't match between my app target and my extension targets.

Once I fixed them up, it worked :)